# Get Two matches for each jobs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like below

Jobs:

> id | user_id | job_title
>
> Matches: id| job_id | user_id

There are one to many relationship between jobs and matches table. One jobs have multiple matches.

I want list of jobs with it's two matches like below :

```
Jobs => [
    '0' => [
        'job_title' => 'abc',
        'Matches' => [
             '0' => [
                 'id',
                 'job_id',
                 'user_id',
             ],
             '0' => [
                 'id',
                 'job_id',
                 'user_id',
             ]
        ]
    ],
    '1' => [
        'job_title' => 'abc',
        'Matches' => [
             '0' => [
                 'id',
                 'job_id',
                 'user_id',
             ],
             '0' => [
                 'id',
                 'job_id',
                 'user_id',
             ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Please help me on this concern. Thanks in advance.

I have search a lot for this issue and most of the blogs give me same solution like below but it is not work for me.

```
set @num := 0, @group := '';

select person, `group`, age
from 
(
   select person, `group`, age,
      @num := if(@group = `group`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @group := `group` as dummy
  from mytable
  order by `Group`, Age desc, person
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: Now we know what you want to get but you didn't explain what is your problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have already search a lot for this issue and almost all the blogs and stack overflow questions gives me same solutions as @bc004346 I have edit my question and add query which is not work for me.

Comment: @Wolen Thanks for your time. I want only two latest records from the sub table. But its give all the records from the sub table because there are no facility to give limit on sub table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract that data using a join and then to create a variable and save on it the row number(@num).

We also need another variable to save the "group" id (job id in this case) as its necessary to restart the row count when a different job appears.

Finally we filter by @num with as much rows you want. Remember matchNO is a calculated field so you cant filter in a where statment, use having instead.

```
set @num := 0, @job := 0;

select j.job_title, m.id, m.job_id, m.user_id,IF(@job = j.id,@num:=@num+1,@num:=1) as matchNO,@job:=j.id
from jobs j 
left join matches m on j.id = m.job_id
having matchNO <= 2;
```

- The row number is necessary to figure out in what row you are.
- The job variable tell you the job in the last row so you can compare and then set @num to 1 again when necesary.

I hope it helps

Comment: Could you please let me know what's not clear on this so I can try to explain better? As I understand this is a mysql query question and Rav is having enough php knowledge to make that work.

Comment: @AndoitzJordán Thanks for your time. Yes this answer covered 50% of the question. I want only two latest recored from the matches table for each jobs. And with this query it's return all the matches records for each jobs.